# Error in AWS source code?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In our code, we delete a message from a sqs queue and get the `deletResponse`.

```
String deleteResponse = sqsClient.deleteMessage(simBridge2ESBUrl, message.getReceiptHandle()).toString();
```

The message is deleted after this call but `deleteResponse` is always `{}`. So we checked the source code and found `DeleteMessageResult::toString` function does only return `{}`.

Below is the AWS source code. The `toString()` and `hashCode()` functions seem to be weird. Is there error in the source code or am I doing it wrong? Thanks.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010-2016 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights
 * Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * 
 */
public class DeleteMessageResult implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this object; useful for testing and
     * debugging.
     *
     * @return A string representation of this object.
     *
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{");
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (obj instanceof DeleteMessageResult == false)
            return false;
        DeleteMessageResult other = (DeleteMessageResult) obj;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hashCode = 1;

        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public DeleteMessageResult clone() {
        try {
            return (DeleteMessageResult) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Got a CloneNotSupportedException from Object.clone() "
                            + "even though we're Cloneable!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See official [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html)  on deleting SQS message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From programming perspective `toString()` is written correctly. Think about what this function does:

> A string representation of this object.

Since `DeleteMessageResult` class has no properties, there is nothing to return. Same applies to `hashCode()`. Two objects of `DeleteMessageResult` are always identical, so they have the same hash every time.

That being said, I do think that `DeleteMessageResult` should contain `ResposeMetadata` with unique `RequestId` as show in [API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessage.html):

```
<DeleteMessageResponse>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>
            b5293cb5-d306-4a17-9048-b263635abe42
        </RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</DeleteMessageResponse>
```

So, yes, this class could (probably, should) be patched to fully back the SQS API.